# Response body is empty for some sites FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm doing some test with Fiddler core and I'm able to intercept the traffic for almost all sites, but for some HTTPS sites I get empty response body.

I have found 2 sites by now:

[Facebook.com](https://facebook.com)
[Google.com](https://google.com)

I have tested other HTTPS sites (including StackOverflow) and I have no problem with them.

This is my code:

```
var content = oSession.ResponseHeaders.FirstOrDefault(
    (item => string.Equals(item.Name, "content-type", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

if (oSession.host.Contains("google.com"))
    if (content != null)
    {
        if (!content.Value.Contains("text/html")) return;
    }
    else return;
else return;
var x = oSession.oResponse;
var body = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString(); // actual response from the server
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(body);
var htmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["html"];
if (htmlNode == null)
{
    return; // no HTML tag -> not an HTML page
}
```

As you can see I get the `content-type` header, then check if the session is from Google and then check if the header value is `text/html`, if it is then I put the response body in the `body` variable...

At this point I put a break point to verify the `body` value but it is empty (""), beside that when I continue the execution the Google home page load anyways, and if I check the session with Fiddler I can see the response body normally.

I have looked in Google and found nothing, also I have checked every response from Google (not only text/HTML) and found nothing that can help.

Comment: Are you sure that your response is a HTTP 200? Your client may have already cached it and therefore the web server answers with HTTP 304 or similar. Such a 3xx response will not have a body.

Comment: I have already solved it, but I haven't had time to publish the answer here. The problem whas that the response was encoded in Brolit